# I have two rows with different id's.I want to add both the rows and display it as One

Tags: count, group-by, sum, rows

I have a derived Table from two different tables using count and group by functions for which the output is like this.

```
Department   DeptID   Count(noofemployees)

HR            1          60
Accounting    19         7
Computers     4          67
Sys admin     6          5
Finance       3          15
Admin         9          12
```

Now I am trying to add and display

```
HR + Accounting + Finance = 10 + 7 + 13 = 30 as HR

Computers + Sys admin = 65 + 5 =70 as Computers

Department   DeptID   Count(noofemployees)

HR            1          30
Computers     4          70
Admin         9          12
```

Can you please help out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to this ,

I could not call the Department name on this but can just show the sum of `COUNT(Noofemployees)` , since we cannot group by

we can use

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Department IN('HR','Accounting','Finance' THEN 1 ELSE 0)HR,
SUM(CASE WHEN Department IN('Computers','sys admin' THEN 1 ELSE 0)computers,
SUM(CASE WHEN Department IN('Admin' THEN 1 ELSE 0)Admin
FROM table_name.
```

this will give me an output:

```
HR  Computers  Admin
30    70         12
```

Not Quite the output I am looking for, but helps for now. 
If anyone can help me getting the output I am looking for that would great.

Thank you